# Maps crashing on samsung s4 4.2.2

Tags: android, maps

> ```
> package com.netvariant.zain.activity;
>  public class StoreMapActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
> private GoogleMap googleMap;
> String longitude="0";
> String latitude="0";
> String title="";
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
>     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
>     longitude = extras.getString("longitude");
>     latitude = extras.getString("lattitude");
>     title= extras.getString("name");
>     try {
>         // Loading map
>         initilizeMap();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> private void initilizeMap() {
>     if (googleMap == null) {
>         double savedLat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
>         double savedLng =Double.parseDouble(longitude);
>         LatLng cameraLatLng = new LatLng(savedLat, savedLng);
>         googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
>                 R.id.map)).getMap();
>         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>         .position(new LatLng( Float.parseFloat(latitude), Float.parseFloat(longitude))).title("Marker")
>         .title(title));
>         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraLatLng, 17));
>         // check if map is created successfully or not
>         if (googleMap == null) {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
>                     "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
>                     .show();
>         }
>     }
> }
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     initilizeMap();
> }
>        }
> ```

This is my map class, on samsung s4 4.2.2 it crashes. I use google play services froyo for it.
The layout is simple, its a fragment. Unfortunately, I dont have s4 myself to detect whats happening. Its being reported by someone trying it on s4 that its crashing. Any helps would be thankful.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
> <fragment
>     android:id="@+id/map"
>     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

---

my manifest file and hope it helps.....

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="com.netvariant.zain.android.ZainApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.RegionalStoresActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.RegionalStoresMeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.UsageActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.StoresActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.PackagePlanActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.CategoriesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.LoadingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.LoginAuthenticationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.SlidingMenuActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.CategoriesNewsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.ArticlesActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.ArticlesNewsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.StoreMapActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.PostPaidMenuVoiceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.PrePaidMenuVoiceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.PrePaidMenuDataActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.PostPaidMenuDataActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.BillsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.ExtrasActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.BillsAmountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.netvariant.zain.activity.CallDetailsInnerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
       <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD6geBmLw7N6gkDy1zCg7Y4yMtf_QnAOMs" />
</application>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file and also logcat.

Comment: As I said dont have logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following,

```
< meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" > 
< /meta-data>
```

in your manifest file immediately below  the first meta-data tag(where you have placed your google api key)

Comment: ok. but whats the integer googleplauy services..i am using froyo google play services

Comment: Have you imported the "google_play_services_froyo" in your project?Paste the above meta data block in your manifest.It worked for me.

Comment: i impored google_play_services_lib , it gives me red on integer google play services version

Comment: Make sure that you are using updated Google play services.And also I saw just now the very first line in your manifest.<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />. What is that?!? Remove that one and replace it with your own package name.